# Angular Selection Model injector error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I added the `'selectionModel'` to my `TestRateCtrl` controller but I get an error:

```
angular.module('RDash', ['selectionModel'])
    .controller('TestRateCtrl', function() {
```

I get this error:

```
Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=MasterCtrl
```

MasterCtrl is my master.js file. If I add 'selectionModel' to my master.js I get a different error.

```
angular.module('RDash', ['selectionModel'])
    .controller('MasterCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'configService', '$cookieStore', MasterCtrl]);
```

Now I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cookieStoreProvider%20%3C-%20%24cookieStore%20%3C-%20MasterCtrl
```

I have the following in my index.html file:

src="components/angular-selection-model/dist/selection-model.js" charset="utf-8">

src="components/angular-selection-model/dist/selection-model.min.js" charset="utf-8">

Answer (score 1):

By doing this would make two different scopes for your application becuase using same name of module if you reinitiallized that module that would be different that the other one which is already declared

say: file A

```
angular.module("RDash", ['selectionModel']);
```

This is defined and in file B

```
var app = angular.module("RDash", ['selectionModel']);
```

so this would cause to have two different app with same name in one application and that two app with same name in different files so its something like to have two different angular module inside on application.

so,

**Replace this**

```
angular.module('RDash', ['selectionModel']) .controller('TestRateCtrl', function() {
```

**by**

```
angular.module('RDash') .controller('TestRateCtrl', function() {
```

**Same thing is happening here again**

And here you are creating a MasterCtrl and adding MasterCtrl as dependencies

**Replace this**

```
angular.module('RDash', ['selectionModel']) .controller('MasterCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'configService', '$cookieStore', MasterCtrl]);
```

**by**

```
angular.module('RDash') .controller('MasterCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'configService', '$cookieStore']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is using the RDash framework (from startangular.com), and wants to use the angular-selection-model library, the way I was able to add the 'selectionModel' to the RDash framework is in the modules.js file as follows:

angular.module('RDash', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'selectionModel']);